# High score Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am making a doodle jump game, and now i am stuck at a moment. The player gets score once he touches the coins, i want to make a highscore, so that when it restarts , or whe ni click on main menu there will be a text that says high scoe and the score you have. i have made the text already. pleas help me!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static GameManager instance = null;
    public GameObject textscoreobject;
    int score;
    Text scoretext;

    void Awake()
    {
        scoretext = textscoreobject.GetComponent<Text>();
        scoretext.text = "Score: " + score.ToString ();
        if (instance == null)

            instance = this;

        else if(instance != null)

            Destroy(gameObject);

    }
    public void Collect(int passedvalue, GameObject passedobject)
    {
        Destroy (passedobject);
        score = score + passedvalue;
        scoretext.text = "Score: " + score.ToString ();
    }
}


using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

    public int value;
    public float rotatespeed;

    void Update () 
    {
        gameObject.transform.Rotate (Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * rotatespeed);
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        GameManager.instance.Collect (value, gameObject);
    }
}
```

Here is the code now somescreens!
https://www.dropbox.com/s/90mf2esf4tqe7xh/Capture.PNG?dl=0
here is where highscore needs to be displayed!
Help me please!

Comment: What isn't working? What part of the code you've shown here relates to your actual problem?

Comment: actually what i showed works, i want you to help me write code for highscore to be saved!

Comment: There are too many possible answers and good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try Google before asking a question here...

(StackExchange rule: *Don't ask about questions you haven't* tried *to find an answer for*) - e.g. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/672869/player-prefs-to-store-high-scores.html

If your actual question is how to save a highscore, use `PlayerPrefs`.

For example, to save a highscore for later (every time you reached a new score, e.g. at the end of the game):

```
if(score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0)) {
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", score);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

And to read it (in a `Start()` or `Awake()` method in your Main Menu), put

```
SomeHighScoreUIText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0);
```

Comment: ok thansk, i will try now

Comment: wait, i need to add all this code inawake? or hwere?

Comment: i don't get it, i have tried more things and it doesn't work!\

Comment: actually it works, but the score isn't diplayed in the main menu but in the game, so when i restart the game it continues adding, it is good it is almost what i need, but i allso need to display that score in the main menu, how to do that?

Comment: thanks for your help, it works perfectly, i have united your code and my code and now it works!

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks; good luck with your game, and good luck learning!